# How to configure Sonar and Maven multilevel modules?

Tags: sonarqube

I encounter issue to configure a multilevel maven modules for Sonar Analysis.

It is working fine with the following structure:

```
parent module
  |- level 1
       |- module with code to analyze
```

But if I add a depth to the module with code to analyze, I'm not able to configure it.

```
parent module
  |- level 1
       |- level 2
           |- module with code to analyze
```

I tried several configurations:

1. with no special configuration: 
   I get an `Can not execute SonarQube analysis: The project 'level 2' is already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project 'level 1'. If you really want to stop directly analysing project 'level 2', please first delete it from SonarQube and then relaunch the analysis of project 'level 1'.` error. I don't want to launch on level 1 because I have my integration tests at the same level, directly in parent module.
2. using skippedModules property on level 1 and level 2: Only the parent module is analyzed.
3. using includedModules by specifying "module with code to analyze": Only the parent module is analyzed.

Does someone has an idea on how to handle it? (I mean without to modifying the hierarchy folder which is really helpful for some other requirements)

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround:
 - I launch mvn clean install on parent project
 - then I launch sonar:sonar at 'level 2' module, I can do it because all the code source to be analyzed is under the same module.

At least it is working on [my sample project](https://github.com/apupier/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/tycho) but currently I didn't handle yet to make it working on my real project.

Answer (score 1):

Building my Maven multi-module project is consistently working for me.  I'm using SonarQube v4.3.

I placed a sonar-project.properties file at the root level of the parent Maven project.

Here's the contents:

```
# Root project information
sonar.projectKey=<I used the project pom's groupId + artifactId>
sonar.projectName=<can be anything>
sonar.projectVersion=<I used the project pom's version>

# Some properties that will be inherited by the modules
sonar.sources=src
```

In my parent project's pom, I declared this property:

```
<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
```

Within the same pom, I declared the following:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I'm building only the parent project, which results in the parent and all of its children getting analyzed by SonarQube.  I'm using:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar
```

or

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have one module in SonarQube as a project. First, you need to remove it and then execute the new analysis.

This happen when a project already exist but in different level (project, module and so on)

Comment: Hi,

already tried, removing the project on Sonar doesn't help.

Thanks anyway

Comment: can you verify that the key does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is related to this JIRA : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4245

The only solution is using old version of Sonar..